# How to define inparaenum in the preamble

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I'm using both `\inparaenum` and `\enumerate` in my thesis and I would like them to set them in the preamble so that each item is set off with *a)*.  I used

```
\setenumerate[0]{\itshape a\upshape)}
```

in the preamble for `\enumerate` but I don't know what to do for \inparaenum.  I tried

```
\renewcommand{\begin{inparaenum}}{\begin{inparaenum}[\itshape a\upshape)]}
```

and I tried

```
\setinparaenum[0]{\itshpae a\upshape)}
```

and neither worked.  Probably those attempts make people cringe, so sorry.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setenumerate[0]{\itshape a\upshape)}
%\renewcommand{\begin{inparaenum}}{\begin{inparaenum}[\itshape a\upshape)]}
%\setinparaenum[0]{\itshpae a\upshape)}

This is a list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item item one
\item item two
\end{enumerate}

This is in a paragraph:
\begin{inparaenum}
\item item one and
\item item two.
\end{inparaenum}
This is in a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly: [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package allows you to define inline lists very conveniently. The (now-)commented settings can be also defined at the preamble globally.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textit{\alph*)}}

\begin{document}

This is a list:
\begin{enumerate}%[label=\textit{\alph*)}]
\item item one
\item item two
\end{enumerate}

This is in a paragraph:
\begin{enumerate*}%[label=\textit{\alph*)}]
\item item one and
\item item two.
\end{enumerate*}
This is in a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear – i'm looking to set the style in the preamble because i have a ton of lists and i don't want to write it out every time and i want to be able to change it easily if i change my mind.  that output is exactly what i'm looking for though.

Comment: @emily Is it better now?

Comment: i get "unknown option 'inline' for package 'enumitem'"...any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @emily If you put `\listfiles` command in your preamble, it will add the version info of the loaded packages in the log file or (the gibberish that your editor spits out :P). Please check that your package is up to date (I have v3.5.2).

Comment: @percuße how we can  change `a) b)...` at `i) ii)...`?

Answer (score 6):

The easy way is part of the `paralist` package (see page 3 of [the manual](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf)). To achieve a) b) c) just start your enumeration with `\begin{enumerate}[a)]` (or `\begin{inparaenum}[a)]`).
For capitals use `A` instead of `a`, for Roman numbers use `i` or `I`, for arabic numbers use `1`. The surrounding formatting, e.g., `)` can be arbitrary, you can escape the special characters using `{a}`, `{A}`, etc.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

This is a list:
\begin{enumerate}[\itshape a)\upshape]
\item item one
\item item two
\end{enumerate}

This is in a paragraph:
\begin{inparaenum}[\itshape a)\upshape]
\item item one and
\item item two.
\end{inparaenum}
This is in a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

In order to make the change permanent, define a new environment, e.g.:

`\newenvironment{paraenum}{\begin{inparaenum}[\itshape a)\upshape]}{\end{inparaenum}}`